# warning: expression implicitly coerced from 'String?' to Any

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3, compiler-warnings

I am getting a couple compiler warnings after running my app, but does not indicate exactly where these warnings appear in my code (at least I am not able to find it). See attached screenshot of where I am receiving these warnings. Thank you in Advance!   [image]

Comment: if you have "print(xy.z)"  , add "as Any" like "print(x.y.z as Any)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This warning occurs when you **print** an optional. The compiler suggests three options to silence the warning. Use the most appropriate one. The warning is harmless.

Comment: I have removed all the print statement from entire project. Still I am seeing 7 Warning Stating same as question.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when I was trying to `print(error)`.
The warning was gone after I changed it to `print(error as Any)`.